# Understanding Icon Indicies in a C# Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, icons, file-type

I have a C# application that needs to define an icon for the project files that the user can save and load when using the application. I know how to set up the registry entries but what I am struggling with is the icon index for the DefaultIcon for the project file extension.

I've added the icon to the Resources file. I've also added the icon to the Resources folder in Visual Studio. Yet when I reboot my PC an index of one has no icon and an index of zero is the application icon.

I tried setting the icon persistence to "Embedded in .resx". Didn't help.

I added a new resource file called PublicIcons.resx, set the access modifier to "Public" and added the icon. Didn't help either.

I tried adding the icon directly to the project and setting the build action to "Embedded Resource". Again, didn't help.

Gaaaa! Why is such a simple task so annoying?

How do I add an icon to a C# project in Visual Studio and then discover the index of that icon so it can be used for a file type?

thanks, Andy

Comment: Project file???  Check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/05/10007461.aspx

Comment: Thanks. However my application has only one public icon - the application icon. How can I add more?

Comment: This question is way too confuzzling, talking about a project file and the need to add more icons.  Windows can only see unmanaged resources, that's why you have to create a .res file if you want to do anything unusual.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Resource file radio button.

Comment: Project files need icons and they have to come from executables. That's the strange way Microsoft designed it.I will try adding an old-fashioned .rc file. Seems weird though that the multitude of resource options in VS2010 can't do this. If this is unusual then what is the usual way of doing it?

Comment: Clarification: project files are the files that the application can save and load. Nothing to do with VS2010 project files.

Comment: So, I tried your suggestion of using the Application tab -> Resource File radio button and it works. What effect will it have on my application to not have a manifest now? Looks like all the assembly info is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I have spent hours today trying to accomplish this simple task - reading about Setup and Deployment projects, ClickOnce, manifest files, fileAssociation tags, Visual Studio 2010 resource files, on and on and on. But here is how to solve the problem in literally two minutes:

In your VS2010 solution add a new empty C++ project: Add -> New Project -> Visual C++ -> Empty Project. I called my "ResourceLibrary".

Right click on the Resource Files folder then choose Add -> Resource... and select the icon.

Right click on the Source Files folder then choose Add -> New Item... -> C++ File. I called my main.cpp. Enter:

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

Then compile and associate your file with icon index zero in ResourceLibrary.exe using the appropriate registry entry and the installer program of your choice!

Simple and effective.